# Resizing my table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to fit my table on the page like this:

[image]

But instead it goes like this:

[image]

With the left side being the end of the page. How do I do this? This is what I have:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Monday-saturday & Full-time new (break after 3 hours) & Full-time new (break after 4 hours) & Part-time new & Total employees working & Minimum employees needed & Additional costs
\\\hline
10:00-11:00 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & \euro0
\\\hline
11:00-12:00 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & \euro 30
\\\hline
12:00-13:00 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 9 & \euro40
\\\hline
13:00-14:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 & \euro0
\\\hline
14:00-15:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 * 6 & \euro0
\\\hline
15:00-16:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 5 & \euro10
\\\hline
16:00-17:00 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & \euro10 
\\\hline
17:00-18:00 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 11 & 9 & \euro0
\\\hline
18:00-19:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & \euro10
\\\hline
19:00-20:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 & \euro40
\\\hline 
20:00-21:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 4 & \euro10
\\\hline

\end{tabular}   


\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different column type. In the following example I switched one `l` to `p{3cm}` to break the column after 3cm.

But please next time provide a complete example including the preamble with any required packages. I had to define the `\euro` command myself since you did not specify the package you used.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\euro}{EUR~}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Monday-saturday & Full-time new (break after 3 hours) & Full-time new (break after 4 hours) & Part-time new & Total employees working & Minimum employees needed & Additional costs
\\\hline
10:00-11:00 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & \euro0
\\\hline
11:00-12:00 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & \euro 30
\\\hline
12:00-13:00 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 9 & \euro40
\\\hline
13:00-14:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 & \euro0
\\\hline
14:00-15:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 * 6 & \euro0
\\\hline
15:00-16:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 5 & \euro10
\\\hline
16:00-17:00 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & \euro10 
\\\hline
17:00-18:00 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 11 & 9 & \euro0
\\\hline
18:00-19:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & \euro10
\\\hline
19:00-20:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 & \euro40
\\\hline 
20:00-21:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 4 & \euro10
\\\hline

\end{tabular}   


\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm sorry, I'll include the preamble next time.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, I mistyped and forgot to check. I'll correct that.

Comment: @Uwe Ziegenhagen: You should change `p{3cm}` to `>{\raggedright}p{3cm}`, loading the array package.

Comment: Better still, load both the `array` and `ragged2e` packages and use `>{\RaggedRight}p{3cm}`. This will maintain hyphenation possiblities (which `\raggedright` does not).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do the following:

- Use a `tabularx` environment instead of `tabular`, and use a modified form of the `X` column type for columns 2 through 7. Like the basic `p` column type, the `X` column type lets material wrap across lines. Compared with the `p` column type, the `X` column type does all the required column width calculations for you. (The default is that all columns of type `X` have the same width; however, that can be changed.) The modification, illustrated in the code below, lets the material in the narrow columns be typeset in *ragged-right mode* instead of fully-justified mode.
- To achieve an open-and-accessible look, get rid of all vertical lines and most interior horizontal lines. Use the macros of the `booktabs` package for the remaining three horizontal lines. You may want to insert a bit of whitespace after every third or fourth row.
- If you want to enable hyphenation of the first words in each cell, use LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. That, or insert `\hspace{0pt}` before "Minimum" and "Additional".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newenvironment{narrowtab}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}}{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{6}{Y} @{}}
\toprule
\begin{narrowtab}Monday--\\Saturday\end{narrowtab} & 
Full-time new (break after 3 hours) & 
Full-time new (break after 4 hours) & 
Part-time new & 
Total employees working & 
Minimum employees needed & 
Additional costs
\\
\midrule
10:00--11:00 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & \euro0\\
11:00--12:00 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & \euro 30\\
12:00--13:00 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 9 & \euro40\\
\addlinespace
13:00--14:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 & \euro0\\
14:00--15:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 6 & \euro0\\
15:00--16:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 5 & \euro10\\
\addlinespace
16:00--17:00 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & \euro10 \\
17:00--18:00 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 11 & 9 & \euro0\\
18:00--19:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & \euro10\\
\addlinespace
19:00--20:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 & \euro40\\ 
20:00--21:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 4 & \euro10\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}   
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose another approach with rotated table heads, a smaller font size and numbers right-aligned between them while left aligned in their column. I also use the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array, makecell, tabularx, rotating, booktabs}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\newcommand{\euro}[1]{\EUR\,#1}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright\small\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format = 2.0,table-number-alignment = left}

\newcommand\till{$ \mkern2mu $--}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\settowidth{\rotheadsize}{Minimum employees}
\renewcommand\cellrotangle{30}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l@{\hskip-2em}*{3}{X}@{}*{3}{S@{\hskip-5.5em}}}
\rothead{\\\ Monday--Saturday} & \rothead{Full-time new\\\scriptsize (break after 3 hours)} & \rothead{Full-time new \\\scriptsize(break after 4 hours)} & \rothead{Part-time new} & {\rothead{Total employees \\working}} & {\rothead{Minimum employees\\ needed}} & {\rothead{Additional costs\\ (\EUR)}}
\\
\toprule
10:00\till 11:00 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 0\\
11:00\till 12:00 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 30 \\
12:00\till 13:00 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 9 & 9 & 40 \\
13:00\till 14:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 & 0 \\
14:00\till 15:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 6 & 0\\
15:00\till 16:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 5 & 10\\
16:00\till 17:00 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 10 \\
17:00\till 18:00 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 11 & 9 & 0 \\
18:00\till 19:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 10 \\
19:00\till 20:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 & 40 \\
20:00\till 21:00 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 10 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]